# How to measure layout performance?

Tags: android, android-layout, profiling

I need to get some objective measures that screen renders faster. Tell me, please, how to measure the time of calculating the size of layout views and their rendering.

I tried to use hierarchyviewer, but it doesn't work properly in my case. It shows zeros for most of views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it before, but I think you can extend your `Layout` parent and override `onMeasure()` like this:

```
@override onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
 float start=(float) System.currentTimeMillis();
 super.onMeasure (widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
 Log.i("ElapsedTime",String.valueOf(((float)System.currentTimeMillis())-start));
}
```

Then use this custom `Layout` as the root for your layout. You can do this for each `View` if you want to calculate them separately.

Comment: Just in case anything wants to do the same several years later ... Make sure to do the same in `onLayout`, since layouting may be expensive too (although measuring usually takes a lot longer)